# Regex number between slash

Tags: regex, string, replace

I have a lot of lines with mark like

```
/* 1 */
/* 2 */
....
/* 1000 */
```

I want to replace them by comma. I came up with a simple regex to use on Notepadd++

```
\/(.*?)\/
```

Works fine, but sometimes some lines has txt like this and matches the regex when should not

```
de produtos /  trazendo inputs qualitativos / estratégicos para a marca
------------^-------------------------------^----------------------
```

I am trying to use /* instead of just / but with no success!

Any suggestion?

Comment: Use: `\/\*.*?\*\/`

Comment: The `/\*+[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/` regex is best if you do not need the text in between `/*` and `*/`

Comment: @anubhava do a answer and I will pick yours... worked like a charm! cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to match `/* ... */` blocks, you may use this regex:

```
\/\*.*?\*\/
```

Since `*` is meta-character in regex, it needs to be escaped as well.

Also it is required to use lazy quantifier `.*?` to avoid matching across the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the work

```
\/\*[\d\s]+\*\/
```

It will match first opening comment, then either digit or space multiple times and then closing comment